# Third party authentication doesn't work from facebook browser

Tags: facebook, google-signin, facebook-login, facebook-browser

I have a web application (React js with Kotlin backend) that has normal email + pw (plus PIN) login, and it also supports 3rd party authentication (Google and Facebook). It works on mobile and web, however, when I open my webpage through Facebook app - which opens it's own browser - and try to log in with 3rd party authentication, I can click on that "Continue as me" button, but then the page refreshes and I'm not logged in. I saw the same thing happen on other sites too, e.g. Figma, Pinterest, etc. I thought it's impossible to log in this way anymore, however, I just noticed that you can actually log in to Stackoverflow this way (so facebook app -> facebook browser -> stack overflow -> 3rd party auth and it works).
Has anyone figured it out how it was possible for Stackoverflow to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. The problem was that when a user clicked on 'Login with FB' button on my site, I sent a request to fb to get back a content of a login window and I created a pop up window where I rendered it, I put on a listener on that pop up window and once it was done, then I got the access token and sent it to backend and logged the user in. On a normal browser it works perfect (both pc and mobile) but as I mentioned above it didn't work in an in app browser like facebook app.
The issue was that facebook app opens a website in it's own browser that doesn't handle any pop ups, so after a successful authentication I saw that nothing happened and it was because we were not redirected to the original window where we should have, and it had the token in the url. So the solution was instead of making this pop up window for FB login, just redirect the user to the fb login page (and stay on the same window), and once the login is successful, just handle the token as is.